# Workflow question: How to specify other StackExchange when closing because the question is on the wrong exchange?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just tried to vote to close a question because it needs to be migrated to another site.  I got as far as this popup:

[image: Popup asking where to migrate the question]

but the question belongs on the Python stackexchange, not blender.meta.

Is there some way to specify other sites in the popup, or are we limited to "not a blender question"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know only moderators and site admins get to pick a different community to migrate questions to.

The dialog I started seeing after becoming a moderator changed, presenting a search box with actual listing of Stack network sites we can pick from.
[image]

From my freshly made research on the subject this has already been proven to be troublesome, with [many sites being overwhelmed by incoming questions rejected from other sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399730/why-does-so-not-add-more-sites-to-this-question-belongs-on-another-site-in-the) and becoming an easy bin for sweeping away unwanted or poorly formed questions.

I can see this being abused and quickly becoming a pass the buck game, where we shove questions away to unsuspecting target sites without much thought, potentially flooding them with off topic questions.

I speculate the [list was once populated with other sites relevant for our frequent off topic reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators), but is now featuring only meta; probably because our site is specific to using Blender the 3D software package, and no other "tangentially related" topics with a valid relevant network site were deemed worthy of being permanently featured in that list.

Of course one can argue that sites like, [image] [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), [image] [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), or even [image] [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) are sometimes relevant, but this was probably abused in the past.

This may also prove an unwelcoming experience to the inexperienced OP which unexpectedly "travels through a magic portal" and quickly finds his question migrated to a completely different "hostile world" where an innocent question gets massively downvoted on a dedicated site where beginner questions are poorly received.

Since I'm also often not that familiar with the rules and valid topics of other communities, I prefer to point the OP to other sites through comments, rather that do it automatically.